# Internal data storage mechanism of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been working with elasticsearch for the past 2 months. I have used both REST approach and API support in different languages to index, get and search data. I also read a lot about elasticsearch and found out it is not a good option to use it as a data store. Why is this? And I'm also curious about how elasticsearch internally stores the indexed data. Any good link or explanation??

Comment: Have a read of this http://blog.smeef.co.uk/elasticsearch-data-structure/ .... I dont think there is a problem using it as a primary data store, its down to the data you wish to store, you can extract the data as you want it to be. So on and so forth. There are use cases of CMS being supported by a ES backend

Comment: Can you provide us with the link saying that it's not a good option to use ES as a data store?

Comment: @eliasah Have a look at [this blog post](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/resiliency-elasticsearch/)

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten! I have already read that one. I was trying to figure out where did `ibsjayanth` find his info. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elastic Search is built on top of Apache Lucene - here's a reference doc on the Lucene index file structure:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_2/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene46/package-summary.html#package_description

Regarding whether or not it's a good option as a data store I think that's more individual opinion and specific use cases than a fact that can be proved. It does not have the transaction support that something like MySQL does if that's what you are looking for. In that case it's somewhat on a par with other NoSQL solutions. This is a pretty decent writeup on the trade-offs and issues: https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-as-nosql/

In the end it depends on what you are doing with your data and what level of robustness you require.